# Why lteOFDMinfo gives the same results for signals with 75 and 100 resource blocks?

Tags: matlab, telecommunication, lte

Why the following commands gives the same result for the LTE downlink signals with 75 resource blocks and 100 resource?

```
       enb = struct('NDLRB',75,'CyclicPrefix','Normal');
       lteOFDMInfo(enb)
```

answer:

```
       SamplingRate: 30720000
               Nfft: 2048
          Windowing: 8
   CyclicPrefixLengths: [160 144 144 144 144 144 144 160 144 144 144 144 144 144]
```

And the same command using 100 resource blocks:

```
      enb = struct('NDLRB',100,'CyclicPrefix','Normal');
      lteOFDMInfo(enb)
```

answer:

```
       SamplingRate: 30720000
               Nfft: 2048
          Windowing: 8
CyclicPrefixLengths: [160 144 144 144 144 144 144 160 144 144 144 144 144 144]
```

I belive that the size of the FFT and the sampling rate were supposed to be different. Am I forgetting something?

function link: https://www.mathworks.com/help/lte/ref/lteofdminfo.html

Comment: I am using the Matlab LTE toolbox.

Comment: A sampling rate 30.72 Msamples/s is valid for a 15-MHz baseband signal (although a smaller value would do), and it gives an FFT size that is a power of 2. From the [book by Dahlman et al.](https://www.amazon.es/4G-LTE-LTE-Advanced-Mobile-Broadband/dp/012385489X): _FFT-based implementations of OFDM are common practice and an FFT size of 2048, with a corresponding sampling rate of 30.72 MHz, is suitable for the wider LTE carrier bandwidths (such as bandwidths of the order of 15 MHz and above)._

Comment: Thanks. Just a curiosity: Is there a way to specify a smaller sampling rate for the signals with 75 resource blocks?

Comment: Not that I know of. The sampling frequency is automatically derived from the `enb` struct

Comment: Glad I could help!